# ASP.NET RadioButtonList events are not triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList in my site and it has a OnTextChanged and OnSelectedIndexChanged events that for an unknown reason do not fire when the selection is changed.
Here is the aspx code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="approvalYesNo" runat="server" OnTextChanged="approvalYesNo_SelectedIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanged="approvalYesNo_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>No need</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Required</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

C# Code (not even starting so it has nothing to do with its content)

```
protected void approvalYesNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

...            
    }
```

any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `AutoPostBack="true"` after `runat="server"`

Comment: It works! thanks. can you please give me a brief explanation of this solution?

Comment: [link]http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/2f73dd/what-is-postback-in-Asp-Net/

[link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e44pOfL_Ly8

every time, when You need to execute some subroutine of control must set autopostback="true"... sometimes, if You use dropdownlist, for example, and You don't need to something happen after changing selection you don't use autopostback or set it to false.